# Pesquisa SQL por mais de um tipo de imóvel, cidade e bairro não funciona corretamente

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, query

Eu peguei um template pronto com alguns problemas no plugins e nas consultas.

Dos 6 campos select para fazer uma procura de imóveis, 3 deles podem selecionar mais de uma vez, tipo de imóvel, cidade e bairro.

A lista desses 3 campos é gerada através da query e exibida com as checkbox antes dos nomes, no caso do Tipo Imóvel seria assim:

[image: Tipo de Imóvel,]

Antes, somente o Tipo de Imóvel podia escolher mais de um item, depois o cliente pediu para que os campos Cidade e Bairro também pudesse escolher mais de um item. Bom, o plugin que utilizo é o jquery.multiselect para fazer isso. Eu conseguir implementar isso, apesar que ele estava voltado para Tipo de Imóvel por causa da descrição "Tipo de Imóvel" no código que depois substituir por "Seleciona um item".

Até aí tudo bem, só que quando faz a pesquisa com mais de um item (Tipo de Imóvel, Cidade e/ou Bairro) somente considera um ultimo item marcado em cada um.

Exemplo: quando marco primeiro Nova Lima e depois eu marco Belo Horizonte, a pesquisa vai retorna só Belo Horizonte.

Eis o código:

```
<!-- BUSCAS -->
        <section class="boxBuscas">
            <div class="centerSite">

                <ul class="nav navBuscas">
                    <li id="bRapida"><a href="javascript:;">Busca <br /> Rápida</a></li>
                    <li id="bCodigo"><a href="javascript:;">Busca <br /> Código</a></li>
                    <li id="bAvancada"><a href="javascript:;">Busca <br /> Avançada</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="tpBuscas boxBuscas">
                    <h3 class="titles" id="encontre">Encontre seu Imóvel.</h3>

                    <?php
                    if ($modulo == "") {
                        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT value, print FROM tipos WHERE codimobiliaria = '$codimobiliaria' ORDER BY print";
                    } else {
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tipos_$modulo WHERE (codimobiliaria='$codimobiliaria') ORDER BY print";
                    }

                    $first_query = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
                    $second_query = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
                    $linhas = mysqli_num_rows($first_query);
                    ?>                


                    <div class="forms bRapida">
                        <form method="GET" id="frmBusca" name="frmBusca" action="<?php echo $url_arquivo; ?>lista.php">
                            <dl class="pretensao">
                                <dt><label id="lblPret" name="lblPret" for="ddlPretensao">Quero:</label></dt>
                                <dd>
                                    <select id="ddlPretensao" name="modulo">
                                        <option value="1">Comprar</option>
                                        <option value="2" selected >Alugar</option>
                                    </select>
                                </dd>
                            </dl>

                            <dl class="tipo">
                                <dt><label id="lbltipo" name="lbltipo" for="ddltipo">Tipo do Imóvel:</label></dt>
                                <dd>
                                    <select id="ddltipo" name="ddltipo" multiple="multiple">
                                        <option value="0" selected="selected">Todos</option>
                                        <?php
                                        //Loop no primeiro campo de tipos de imovel.
                                        for ($i = 0; $i < $linhas; $i++) {
                                            $type_01 = mysqli_fetch_array($first_query);
                                            echo "<option value=\"$type_01[value]\">$type_01[value]</option>";
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                            <script type="text/javascript">$(function () {
                                    $('select[id=ddltipo]').multiselect();
                                });</script>

                            <?php

                            $sql_cidade = "SELECT cidade FROM vendas WHERE codimobiliaria = $codimobiliaria GROUP BY cidade";
                            $res = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql_cidade);
                            ?>

                            <dl class="tipo" >
                                <dt><label id="lblCidade" name="lblCidade" for="ddlCidade">Cidade:</label></dt>
                                <dd>
                                    <select id="cidade" name="cidade" multiple="multiple">
                                        <option value="0" selected="selected">Cidade</option>

                                        <?php
                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
                                            echo "<option value='" . $row['cidade'] . "'> " . utf8_encode($row['cidade']) . "</option>";
                                        }
                                        ?>


                                    </select>
                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                            <script type="text/javascript">$(function () {
                                    $('select[id=cidade]').multiselect();
                                });</script>


                            <?php
                            if ($modulo == "") {
                                $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT value, print FROM bairros WHERE (codimobiliaria='$codimobiliaria') ORDER BY print";
                            } else {
                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM bairros_$modulo WHERE (codimobiliaria='$codimobiliaria') ORDER BY print";
                            }

                            $first_query = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
                            $second_query = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
                            $linhas = mysqli_num_rows($first_query);
                            ?>

                            <dl class="tipo">
                                <dt><label id="lblBairro">Bairro:</label></dt>
                                <dd>
                                    <select id="ddlBairro" name="ddlBairro" multiple="multiple">
                                        <option value="0" selected="selected">Bairro</option>

                                        <?php
                                        //Faz o loop com os registros de bairro dentro do Box de select.
                                        for ($i = 0; $i < $linhas; $i++) {
                                            $type_01 = mysqli_fetch_array($first_query);
                                            echo utf8_encode("<option value=\"$type_01[value]\">$type_01[print]</option>");
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                            <script type="text/javascript">$(function () {
                                    $('select[id=ddlBairro]').multiselect();
                                });</script>


                            <dl class="vagas">
                                <dt><label id="lblQts" name="lblQts" for="ddlQts">Quartos:</label></dt>
                                <dd>
                                    <select id="ddlQts" name="ddlQts">
                                        <option value="">Quartos</option>
                                        <option value="1">A partir de 1</option>
                                        <option value="2">A partir de 2</option>
                                        <option value="3">A partir de 3</option>
                                    </select>
                                </dd>
                            </dl>

                            <div class='size1'><dl class="valorMax">
                                    <dt><label id="lblValorMax" name="lblValorMax" for="txtValorMax">Valor máximo:</label></dt>
                                    <dd>
                                        <select name="ddlValorMax" id="ddlValorMax" />
                                        </select>
                                    </dd>
                                </dl>
                            </div>

                            <input type="submit" id="btnEnviar" class='' value="Buscar" />
                            <input type="hidden" id="remetente"  value="1" /></form>

                        <div class="clearboth"></div>
                    </div><!-- .bRapida -->

                    <div class="forms bCodigo">
                        <form method="GET" id="frmBusca" name="frmBusca" action="<?php echo $url_arquivo; ?>listagem.php">


                            <dl class="pretensao">
                                <dt><label id="modulo" name="modulo" for="modulo">Quero:</label></dt>
                                <dd>
                                    <select id="modulo" name="modulo">
                                        <option value="vendas">Comprar</option>
                                        <option value="aluguel">Alugar</option>
                                    </select>
                                </dd>
                            </dl>                    

                            <p>( Digite o código dos imóveis desejados. Exemplo: CA0001, CA0002 )</p>
                            <input id="ref" type="text" name="ref" onblur="if (this.value == '') {
                                        this.value = 'Código';
                                    }" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Código') {
                                                this.value = '';
                                            }" value='Código' />
                            <input type="submit" id="btnEnviar" class='' value="Buscar" />

                            <input type="hidden" id="remetente"  value="1" /></form>
                    </div><!-- .bCodigo -->

                    <div class="forms bAvancada">
                    </div><!-- .bAvancada -->
                </div><!-- .tpBuscas -->

                <div class="clearboth"></div>
            </div><!-- .centerSite -->
        </section><!-- .boxBuscas -->
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

EDIT: Um detalhe que só depois percebi. É o arquivo lista.php onde a action manda. Nele onde recebe os dados da pesquisa e mostra a busca selecionada.

```
<div id="pageListagem" class="pageInternal listagemPadrao">

    <div id="listImovel">

<?php

//$codigo_imovel = $_GET['ref'];

$modulo = $_GET['pretensao'];
$pes_tipo_imovel = $_GET['tipo'];
$pes_cidade = $_GET['cidade2'];
$pes_bairro = $_GET['ddlBairro'];
$pes_quartos = $_GET['ddlQts'];
$pes_valor = $_GET['ddlValorMax']; 


if($modulo == '1'){ 
    $tabela = 'vendas';
    $oque = 'Valor de venda:';
    $pasta = 'img_vendas/';
}elseif($modulo == '2'){    
    $tabela = 'aluguel';
    $oque = 'Valor de Locação:';    
    $pasta = 'img_aluguel/';    
} 

?>        

        <!-- listagem de imoveis -->
        <div class="listagemImovel">

        <?php 

        //$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $tabela WHERE codimobiliaria = '$codimobiliaria' && imovel != 'Industrial' && imovel != 'Rural'";

        if($pes_cidade != '0'){
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $tabela WHERE codimobiliaria = '$codimobiliaria' && cidade = '$pes_cidade' && imovel != 'Industrial' && imovel != 'Rural'";  
        }if($pes_bairro != '0'){
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $tabela WHERE codimobiliaria = '$codimobiliaria' && bairro = '$pes_bairro' && imovel != 'Industrial' && imovel != 'Rural'";  
        }if($pes_tipo_imovel != '0'){
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $tabela WHERE codimobiliaria = '$codimobiliaria' && imovel = '$pes_tipo_imovel' && imovel != 'Industrial' && imovel != 'Rural'"; 
        }if($pes_quartos != ''){
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $tabela WHERE codimobiliaria = '$codimobiliaria' && nquartos >= '$pes_quartos' && imovel != 'Industrial' && imovel != 'Rural'";                  
        }if($pes_valor != '99999999'){
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $tabela WHERE codimobiliaria = '$codimobiliaria' && preco <= '$pes_valor' && imovel != 'Industrial' && imovel != 'Rural'";                   
        }if($pes_tipo_imovel != '0' && $pes_cidade != '0'){
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $tabela WHERE codimobiliaria = '$codimobiliaria' && imovel = '$pes_tipo_imovel' && cidade = '$pes_cidade' && imovel != 'Industrial' && imovel != 'Rural'";   
        }if($pes_tipo_imovel != '0' && $pes_cidade != '0' && $pes_bairro != '0'){
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $tabela WHERE codimobiliaria = '$codimobiliaria' && imovel = '$pes_tipo_imovel' && cidade = '$pes_cidade' && bairro = '$pes_bairro' && imovel != 'Industrial' && imovel != 'Rural'"; 
        }if($pes_tipo_imovel != '0' && $pes_cidade != '0' && $pes_bairro != '0' && $pes_quartos != '0'){
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $tabela WHERE codimobiliaria = '$codimobiliaria' && imovel = '$pes_tipo_imovel' && cidade = '$pes_cidade' && bairro = '$pes_bairro' && nquartos >= '$pes_quartos' && imovel != 'Industrial' && imovel != 'Rural'";   
        }if($pes_tipo_imovel != '0' && $pes_cidade != '0' && $pes_bairro != '0' && $pes_quartos != '0' && $pes_valor != '99999999'){
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $tabela WHERE codimobiliaria = '$codimobiliaria' && imovel = '$pes_tipo_imovel' && cidade = '$pes_cidade' && bairro = '$pes_bairro' && nquartos >= '$pes_quartos' && preco <= '$pes_valor' && imovel != 'Industrial' && imovel != 'Rural'";  
        }if($pes_tipo_imovel == '0' && $pes_cidade == '0' && $pes_bairro == '0' && $pes_quartos == '' && $pes_valor == '99999999'){
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $tabela WHERE codimobiliaria = '$codimobiliaria' && imovel != 'Industrial' && imovel != 'Rural'";            
        }

        ?>

            <?php
                $query2 = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql2);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($query2)){
               $reg2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2);

            }

             ?>         

        <?php $linhas = mysqli_num_rows($query2); ?>

            <header class="headerListagem">
                <h2 class="titleBox">Resultado da Busca </h2>
                <p class="qntImoveis"><strong><?=$linhas?></strong> imóveis encontrado(s)</p>                
                <div class="opcoes">
                    <div id="dv_order" name="dv_order" class="filtros"><p>Ordenar por: </p>
                        <select id='ddlorder' name='ddlorder'>
                            <option value='menor' selected='selected' >menor valor</option>
                            <option value='maior' >maior valor</option>
                        </select>

                        <input type="hidden" id="order" name="order" value="3"></div>

                        <div class="modoVisualizacao">
                            <p>Visualizar em:</p>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="btn verTab" rel="verTab"><span></span>Tabela</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="btn verLista ativo" rel="verLista"><span></span>Lista</a></li
                            ></ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="clearboth"></div>
            </header>

            <div class="todosImoveis">

             <?php
             if($linhas != '0'){

                $query2 = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql2);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($query2)){


               while ($reg2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) {

               $imovel = $reg2['imovel'];
               $codigo_imovel = $reg2['codimovel'];
               $bairro = $reg2['bairro'];
               $cidade = $reg2['cidade'];
               $uf = $reg2['uf'];
               $quartos = $reg2['quartos'];
               $suites = $reg2['suites'];
               $valor = $reg2['preco'];
               $vagas = $reg2['garagens'];
             ?>    



                <div class='imovel'>
                    <figure><!-- VG Foto: 439978337 -->
                            <a href="<?php echo $url_arquivo; ?>imovel/imovel.php?modulo=<?=$modulo;?>&def=med&codimovel=<?=$reg2['codimovel']?>&form=&tipoPagina=1" title="" >
                                <img src="http://www.imobiliaria.com.br/web/<?php echo $reg2['codimobiliaria'] . '/' . $pasta . $reg2['codimobiliaria'] . '_' .$reg2['codimovel']; ?>_01.jpg" alt="" />
                            </a>
                            <a class='sombra' href='<?php echo $url_arquivo; ?>imovel/imovel.php?modulo=<?=$modulo;?>&def=med&codimovel=<?=$reg2['codimovel']?>&form=&tipoPagina=1'>
                            </a>
                            <a class='geral' href='<?php echo $url_arquivo; ?>imovel/imovel.php?modulo=<?=$modulo;?>&def=med&codimovel=<?=$reg2['codimovel']?>&form=&tipoPagina=1'>
                            </a>
                       </figure>
                       <div class='features'>
                        <h3><?php echo $imovel; ?>
                        </h3>
                            <h4><?php echo $bairro; ?> - <?php echo $cidade ?>/<?php echo $uf ?>
                            </h4>
                                <p class='ref'>Ref.: <?php echo $codigo_imovel; ?>
                                </p>
                                    <div class='importantes in_dorm'>
                                        <span><?php echo $quartos; ?>
                                        </span> dormitório(s)
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='importantes in_suites'>
                                        <span><?php echo $suites; ?>
                                        </span> suíte(s)
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='importantes in_garagens'>
                                        <span><?php echo $vagas; ?>
                                        </span> vaga(s)
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='preco'>
                                        <span><?php echo $oque; ?>
                                        </span>
                                    <div class='clearboth'>
                                    </div> <?php echo 'R$ ' . $valor . ',00'; ?> 
                                    </div>      
                                    <div class='valor'>
                                    </div>              
                                    <div class='favoritos'>
                                        <a href='<?php echo $url_arquivo; ?>impressaod.php?modulo=<?=$modulo?>&def=med&codimovel=<?=$reg2['codimovel']?>&form=&tipoPagina=1' class='thickbox' title='Ficha completa do imóvel'>Ficha do Imóvel</a>

                                        <br>
                                            <a class='maisinfo btn'  href='index.php' >
                                            <img width="30px" height="30px" src="img/voltar.png"/><br>
                                            Voltar
                                            </a>
                                    </div>
                                            <a class='maisinfo btn' href='<?php echo $url_arquivo; ?>imovel/imovel.php?modulo=<?=$modulo;?>&def=med&codimovel=<?=$reg2['codimovel']?>&form=&tipoPagina=1'>Mais informações
                                            </a>    
                            </div>
                       </div>

              <?php 
            }
        }else{
            for ($i=0; $i < 7; $i++) { 
            ?>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="thumbnailDestaque watermark_small" src="images/img-teste.png"  height="90" width="120">
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php 
            }
        }
             }if($linhas == '0'){

                 echo '<script> alert("Não existem imóveis cadastrados dentro desses parâmetros de pesquisa!"); window.opener.location="$url_arquivo"; </script>';

                 }
         ?>                 

            </div><!-- .todosImoveis -->


            <footer>
                <div class="opcoes bottom">
                    <?php /*?><div id="dv_page"><ul class="paginacao">
<li class="pagina"><strong>Página: 1 de 4</strong></li>
<li class="proximo"><a valor="2" href="#">Próximo</a></li>
<li class="ultimo"><a valor="4" href="#">Último</a></li><li class="irpagina">
</ul>
<input type="hidden" id="page" name="page" value="1"><input type="hidden" id="page" name="page" value="1"></div><?php */?>

                </div><!-- .opcoes.bottom -->

                <div class="clearboth"></div>
            </footer>
        </div><!-- .listagemImovel -->

        <div class="clearboth"></div>
    </div><!-- #listImovel -->

    <div class="clearboth"></div>
</div><!-- #pageListagem -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Anderson, não saco nada de php, mas o sql eu entendo um pouquinho... Se você fizesse a consulta inserindo Like + varíaveis tipo:

```
select * 
from Tabela
Where Id_Cidade LIKE '%%%'
AND Id_Bairro LIKE '%%%'
```

Eu tenho uma estrutura parecida em um projeto. Quando o cliente não selecionar nada, passa null ou string vazia e eu faço um if e passo % para a variável, ou seja se o cliente não selecionar nada pega tudo. Assim o sql ficaria assim:

```
select * 
from Tabela
Where Id_Cidade LIKE @cidade
AND Id_Bairro LIKE @bairro
```